# Adding a shadow effect to a vector drawable

Tags: android, xml, shadow, vector-graphics, elevation

I want to add shadow effect (or elevation) to the vector drawable.

for example

1.My first file contains a download icon in `ic_file_download_black_24dp.xml`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF2e2e2e"
    android:pathData="M19,9h-4V3H9v6H5l7,7 7,-7zM5,18v2h14v-2H5z"/>
```

2.My second file contains a round shape in `round_shape.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#fffbc02d" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

3.Now, I'm combining these two files to create single layered-drawable like this which called `layered_download_icon.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_shape" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp" />
</layer-list>
```

Which gives me the overall image as shown below

[image]

> Now I want to give elevation to the download icon placed inside the
>   yellow circle. How can I able to achieve that??

P.S. I'm setting `layered_download_icon` to `srcCompat` in my ImageButton.